# Apps Script error: "Exception: Illegal argument" (with no more information): How to find the specific error?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ide

That's it, no more information is given:

[image: screenshot]

The only idea that comes to my mind is adding try-catch in different parts of the code, and with a lot of patience, find it.

Any other better idea?

Comment: Execution page > see logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#exception_logging

---

### Exception logging

Exception logging sends unhandled exceptions in your script project code to Cloud Logging, along with a stack trace.

To view exception logs, follow the steps below:

1. Open the Apps Script project.
2. At the left, click **Executions**.
3. At the top, click **Add a filter > Status**.
4. Select the **Failed** and **Timed out** checkboxes.

You can also [view logged exceptions in the GCP console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#viewing_cloud_logs_and_error_reports_in_the_google_cloud_platform_console) if your script project is using a [standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects) that you have access to.

---

*To check your project has enabled exception logging:*

1. Open the script project.
2. At the left, click **Project Settings**.
3. Select the **Log uncaught exceptions to Cloud Operations** checkbox.

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#enable_exception_logging